# Redux - Filter / Delete multiple items from array of objects. Items to be filtered given in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a initial state variable that is an array of objects and want to filter / delete multiple objects given in another array containing the id's of the objects to be filtered in the payload

```
const initialState = {
    data: [
        {
            name: "apple", 
            id: 1
        }, 
        {
            name: "orange", 
            id: 2
        }, 
        {
            name: "broccoli", 
            id: 3
        }, 
        {
            name: "spinach", 
            id: 4
        }, 
    ]
}

export default (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
    switch (type) {    
    case FILTER_ITEMS:
        //filteredArray = 
        return {
            ...state, 
            data: filteredArray
        }
}
```

I want to filter items from the initialState that do not have the id's as given in the array inside the payload

```
payload = {
   excludeIds = [2,4]
}
```

So after the reducer runs the initialState should be changed to:

```
state = {
    data: [
        {
            name: "apple", 
            id: 1
        }, 
        {
            name: "broccoli", 
            id: 3
        }, 
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.filter()` with `Array.includes()` to take all items, which `id` doesn't appear in excluded array:

```js
const initialState = {"data":[{"name":"apple","id":1},{"name":"orange","id":2},{"name":"broccoli","id":3},{"name":"spinach","id":4}]}

const state = initialState;
const payload = {
  excludeIds: [2, 4]
}

const result = state.data.filter(o => !payload.excludeIds.includes(o.id))

console.log(result)
```

And in the reducer:

```
export default (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
    switch (type) {    
    case FILTER_ITEMS:
        const data = state.data.filter(o => !payload.excludeIds.includes(o.id))
        return {
            ...state, 
            data
        }
}
```

You can use a `Set` if the array of excludes might be large, since the complexity of getting an item from a Set is O(1):

```js
const initialState = {"data":[{"name":"apple","id":1},{"name":"orange","id":2},{"name":"broccoli","id":3},{"name":"spinach","id":4}]}

const state = initialState;
const payload = {
  excludeIds: [2, 4]
}

const exclude = new Set(payload.excludeIds)

const result = state.data.filter(o => !exclude.has(o.id))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: The worst case time complexity for this would be O(n^2), is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a Set based answer.

Comment: Perfect, this is much more efficient. Its O(n) now. A little overhead of converting to a set but much faster than O(n^2)

Comment: O(n + m) where m is length of excluded (Set creation).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf function` of array.

```
filteredArray = state.data.filter(ele => payload.excludeIds.indexOf(ele.id) < 0 ? true : false)
```

Tested:

```js
const initialState = {
    data: [
        {
            name: "apple", 
            id: 1
        }, 
        {
            name: "orange", 
            id: 2
        }, 
        {
            name: "broccoli", 
            id: 3
        }, 
        {
            name: "spinach", 
            id: 4
        }, 
    ]
}

const payload = {
   excludeIds: [2,4]
}

filteredArray = initialState.data.filter(ele => payload.excludeIds.indexOf(ele.id) < 0 ? true : false)

console.log(filteredArray)
```

Comment: Your answer is very clean too, just accepted @OriDori's answer because it is more efficient. Your time complexity is O(n^2) vs O(n)

Comment: The other answer changed it from an array to a set. A set uses a hash function so lookups are O(1)